# Null unicode in a clipboard does not paste

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button in wpf that when clicked does the following:

`Clipboard.SetText("a\u0000b")`

When I try and paste the contents of the clipboard into notepad all i get is:

`a`

How can I get the entire string?

If I render this string in a wpf control, i see `a[square thing]b`. In other words, the view control does not terminate at a null unicode character.

Comment: What is the result that you are expecting?

Comment: Im going to guess he expect "a" like youd get in c++

Comment: I would expect the string in the clipboard to match the string that is rendered in a wpf control. In other words, "a[blah]b"

Comment: Use the overloaded method [Clipboard.SetText(String text, TextDataFormat format)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textdataformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the data format. Default format is unicode.

Comment: @pasty I have many unicode characters that I need to support. The null unicode is, sadly, one of them. Think internationalization with control codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to find if you can copy text with NUL in Windows, and it presumably is not possible. Maybe you could temporarily replace NUL with some other character, which should never appear in any text you process (although it probably will one day, as Murphy's law states), then open the text file and convert all occurrences of this character back to NUL?

```
var text = "a\u0000b";
var textToCopy = text.Replace("\u0000", "\u3f45");

Clipboard.SetText(textToCopy);

// Next paste the contents to the file and reverse the replacement there
```

It is a workaround, but if you're the one using those text files, it might be worth a try.